# Cocos2dx for Windows Phone : VS2012 raise bunch of errors

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8, cocos2d-x

I am porting a game based on Cocos2dx from iOS to Windows Phone 8. The problem here is after I change the fix all the errors of differences of API, I got a bunch of syntax errors, undeclared variable (although these variable is declared). Here is my sample code:
The .h file:

```
#ifndef __Bomb__
#define __Bomb__

#include "MoveableObject.h"

typedef enum BombType {
    BombTypeElectrical,
    BombTypeIce,
    BombTypeChemical,
    BombTypeSmall,
    BombTypeBig
} BombType;

class Bomb : public MoveableObject {
public:
    Bomb() {};
    Bomb(const char* szName);
    virtual ~Bomb() {};

    void setType(int nType) { m_nType = nType; };

    int getType() { return m_nType; };
    bool isExploding() { return m_bExploding; };
    int bombTypeForName(const char* szName);

    void expode();
    void activate();
    void finishExploding();

protected:
    bool m_bExploding;
    int m_nType;
};

#endif
```

And the error is mark here:

```
Bomb::Bomb(const char* szName) : MoveableObject(szName), m_bExploding(false) {
    m_nType = this->bombTypeForName(szName);
}
```

Error 28 error C3861: 'm_bExploding': identifier not found
Anyone had this problem before? How could I solved these problems like this (there are total 420 errors)?. Any help appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Is it not finding the header for the Bomb class?

Comment: No, I have included Bomb.h in Bomb.cpp, and the compiler doesn't show the error (underline the variable), but when I built the project, it is showed in the error list

Comment: Post some more of the errors.

Comment: Probably not the cause of your error, but you have undefined behaviour. Any indetifier with two consecutive underscores is reserved for your compiler and must not be used in user code. Dtto for an identifier starting with underscore followed by uppercase letter.

Comment: Thank @Angew, but I there are more problems such as syntax error or undefined class or namespace. Here they are:
CCAnimate* wagTailAnimate = CCAnimate::actionWithAnimation(wagTailAnimation);
  CCDelayTime* delayAction = CCDelayTime::actionWithDuration(2.5);
  CCCallFunc* callFuncAction = CCCallFunc::actionWithTarget(this, callfunc_selector(Player::dogWagTail));
  CCFiniteTimeAction* wagTailAction = CCSequence::actions(wagTailAnimate, delayAction, callFuncAction, NULL);
and here is the error:
Error 431 error C2653: 'CCSequence' : is not a class or namespace name

Comment: @user2396783 Whenever you're getting many errors (tens or more), only the first one is usually relevant and the rest are the compiler incorrectly recovering from the first one. Is the `m_bExploding` error the first one you got?

Comment: Here is the syntax error :
for (TiXmlElement* pElement = pDocElement->FirstChildElement("animation"); pElement; pElement = pElement->NextSiblingElement())
the error: Error 292 error C2059: syntax error : ')'

Comment: @Angew: No, it's not. Where is the first error in the errors list? The first line or the last?

Comment: In the VS error list, you can sort by any field, but by default, the first error is on the topmost line.

Answer (score 0):

I think the errors are because of the different versions of cocos2d-x and WP8 port.
there is a newer version of WP8 port available:
http://www.cocos2d-x.org/news/98

you are probably using the old version 0.13. There are a lot of syntax (function signatures) changes and thus the errors. Try the version 2.0 in the link given. It has the same API as cocos2d-x v2.1